# Accessing "this" in asynchronous callback function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, this, setinterval

How would I achieve to reference the parent's "this" from inside an asynchronous callback function like in the snippet below?

```
var imaginaryAjaxCall = function (fn) {
    setInterval(fn, 1000);
}

function parent() {
    this.foobar = "foo";

    imaginaryAjaxCall(function() {
       this.foobar = "bar"; 
    });
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/r0ueon53/11/

**Edit:**
I rushed the question, and botched it up. Sorry for rendering some comments irrelevant with this edit.

Comment: Not sure where "this" is being used since it is not in the code, but learn about [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: `setInterval( fn, 0 )` waits for the main script to finish before running `fn` even though the time is set to zero.

Comment: @epascarello `this` is not an issue here. It's being properly cached with `that = this`.

Comment: Then your previous comment doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript runs on a single thread. When you set `fn` to run on an interval, you accessed a DOM Api that acts in an asynchronous way (even though it isn't actually asynchronous.) What happens is the DOM api will insert a callback into the callback queue every time `interval` is passed. So, every 0ms (well, it's actually closer to 4ms but that's another topic) `fn` will be inserted into the callback queue.

Now, callbacks in the callback queue only get ran when the callstack is empty, so, the callback doesn't get ran until after

```
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = this.foobar;
```

is ran, which is why it outputs "foo" instead of "bar".

http://jsfiddle.net/r0ueon53/13/

If you delay that line by a second, you'll see it output "bar" instead.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = that.foobar;
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r0ueon53/12/

this works because `setTimeout` will insert it's callback into the callback queue 1 second later, thus after the setInterval callback that changed the value to "bar".

---

Obviously, when dealing with ajax, using a setTimeout to fix this isn't going to be consistent due to differences in network speed. You should instead just move the .innerHTML up into the callback that you passed to the ajax call.